# Consulta de dados em um datagrid (programa de cadastro)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, propriedade

O problema que eu estou tendo é que eu não se como exibir na `datagrid` só o nome dos usuários para ser possível a consulta de cada cadastro nesse banco quando selecionado, e aí exibindo todos aqueles dados que eu já coloquei e mais se o dado informado foi CPF ou CNPJ.

Estou usando Windows Forms Application com C#.

Abaixo e estou colocando o meu código.

```
List<Pessoa> listcadastro = new List<Pessoa>();


    public class Pessoa
    {

        private string nome;
        private string endereço;
        private int ano_nascimento;
        private string telefone;
        private int idade;

        public string Nome
        {
            get
            {
                return nome;
            }

            private set
            {
                nome = value;
            }
        }

        public string Endereço
        {
            get
            {
                return endereço;
            }

            private set
            {
                endereço = value;
            }
        }

        public int Ano_nascimento
        {
            get
            {
                return ano_nascimento;
            }

            private set
            {
                ano_nascimento = value;
            }
        }

        public int Idade
        {
            get
            {
                return idade;
            }

            private set
            {
                idade = value;
            }
        }

        public string Telefone
        {
            get
            {
                return telefone;
            }

            private set
            {
                telefone = value;
            }
        }

        public Pessoa(string nome, string endereço, int ano_nascimento, string telefone)
        {
            this.nome = nome;

            this.endereço = endereço;

            this.ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;

            this.telefone = telefone;

            this.idade = DateTime.Now.Year - ano_nascimento;

        }
    }

            //Classe Fisica herdada da classe Pessoa
    public class Fisica : Pessoa
    {
        private string nCPF;


        public Fisica(string nome, string endereço, int ano_nascimento, string telefone, string nCPF)
            : base(nome, endereço, ano_nascimento, telefone)
        {
            this.nCPF = nCPF;
        }

        public string CPF
        {
            get
            {
                return nCPF;
            }

            private set
            {
                nCPF = value;
            }
        }


    }

    //Classe Juridica herdada da classe Pessoa
    public class Juridica : Pessoa
    {
        private string nCNPJ;

        public Juridica(string nome, string endereço, int ano_nascimento, string telefone, string nCNPJ)
            : base(nome, endereço, ano_nascimento, telefone)
        {
            this.nCNPJ = nCNPJ;
        }

        public string CNPJ
        {
            get
            {
                return nCNPJ;
            }

            private set
            {
                nCNPJ = value;
            }
        }


    }


private void bt_salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listcadastro.Add(new Pessoa(txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, int.Parse(txt_ano.Text), txt_telefone.Text));

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = listcadastro;


}





private void excluirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Está dando erro? Tirando o fato de você não estar usando os GET e SET do C#, bem como já lhe mostrei em respostas anteriores, não vejo maiores problemas em seu código.

Comment: Poderia melhorar sua dúvida? Estám confuso entender o que você quer e onde você está tendo problemas.

Comment: Já atualizei a minha pergunta e o código.

Comment: A resposta do @bigown não lhe serve?

Comment: É que eu preciso saber como consultar os dados de cada cadastro, mas só exibir o nome do usuario no datagrid e depois que for selecionado, aí sim exibir o resto (e mais o cpf/cnpj que eu ainda não estou exibindo).

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade este código pode ser extremamente simplificado só usando propriedades. Desta forma atende todas necessidades descritas na pergunta.

E ainda mudaria algumas outras pequenas coisas cosméticas.

O que está fazendo com o construtor não chama sobrecarga.

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {}
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Endereço { get; set; }
    public int Ano_nascimento { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public Pessoa(string nome, string endereço, int ano_nascimento, string telefone) {
        Nome = nome;
        Endereço = endereço;
        Ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;
        Telefone = telefone;
        Idade = DateTime.Now.Year - ano_nascimento;
    }
}

public class Fisica : Pessoa {  
    public string NmmCPF { get; private set; }
    public Fisica(string nome, string endereço, int ano_nascimento, string telefone, string nCPF)
        : base(nome, endereço, ano_nascimento, telefone) {
            this.NmmCPF = nCPF;
    }
}

public class Juridica : Pessoa {
    public string NumCnpj { get; private set; }
    public Juridica(string nome, string endereço, int ano_nascimento, string telefone, string nCNPJ)
        : base(nome, endereço, ano_nascimento, telefone) {
            NumCnpj = nCNPJ;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jJzhlY). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cBu16H). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/SimpleProoperty.cs).

Comment: A única coisa que eu mudaria aqui é colocar o private set; para respeitar o encapsulamento do código original.

Comment: @ErickGallani é verdade, eu comi bola nessa. Obrigado.

Comment: É que eu preciso saber como consultar os dados de cada cadastro, mas só exibir o nome do usuário no datagrid e depois que for selecionado, aí sim exibir o resto (e mais o cpf/cnpj que eu ainda não estou exibindo)

Comment: @beginner nada disto está na pergunta, mesmo esse comentária não elucida nada sobre seu problema.

Comment: Eu tinha escrito no segundo parágrafo da pergunta, agora excluí o primeiro.

Comment: Você falou alguma coisa por cima, mas não tem nada disso no seu código.

Comment: Sim, é porque eu não sei como fazer. Só consegui exibir os dados nome, endereço, ano e telefone direto no datagrid, não do jeito que eu expliquei que estou tentando.

Comment: Aí a pergunta não é adequada para o site, aqui ajudamos as pessoas com dificuldades, não para fazer por elas. Procure um livro, faça um bom curso, depois quando estiver com dúvidas pode perguntar aqui.

Comment: Mas a minha pergunta é: como consultar esses dados cadastrais a partir do nome que foi cadastrado anteriormente? Eu só estou conseguindo mostrar todos os dados direto, não só o nome da pessoa e quando eu selecionar ele aí sim abre os dados cadastrados.

Comment: consegui sozinho mesmo